# DNN ASP Only show on homepage

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, dotnetnuke

Wondering if I can do something like this in my DNN skin to only show some html on the homepage and vice versa on the inner-pages with an else statement.

`<% if ((url = "/" | url = "")) { %> Doesn't work… <% } %>`

Also would be nice to know where the documentation is for this kinda stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax errors. If you are using classic-asp then

```
<% if (url = "/" or url = "") then
your code
    end if
  %>
```

Comment: Thanks but I got this "Error: path/to/default.ascx(98)error CS1026: ) expected"